# How to show nested JSON value in table header & row

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I would like to show the nested JSON values in table header and row as per screenshot.

[image]

However, my current code show me as per below.

[image]

How can I get the result of the first screenshot?

Here is my code:

```js
var tbl_ss564_ib_jsonData = [
 {
  "S_No": "1",
  "SS564 Metric": "Power Usage Effectiveness(PUE)",
  "Baseline": "2.2*",
  "DC": [ 
    {"A": "2.4"},
    {"B": "2.61"},
    {"C": "2.46"},
    {"D": "2.25"},
    {"E": "2.11"},
    {"F": "3.75"},
    {"G": "2.08"},
    {"H": "2.17"},
    {"I": "1.85"},
    {"J": "2.57"},
    {"K": "2.42"}
   ]
 }
]
    
    var sortAscending = true;
    var tbl_ss564_ib = d3.select('#ss564_ib_page_wrap').append('table');
    var title_ss564_ib = d3.keys(tbl_ss564_ib_jsonData[0]);
    var header_ss564_ib = tbl_ss564_ib.append('thead').append('tr')
                     .selectAll('th')
                     .data(title_ss564_ib).enter()
                     .append('th')
                     .text(function (d) {
                       return d;
                      })
                     .on('click', function (d) {
                      header_ss564_ib.attr('class', 'header');
                      
                      if (sortAscending) {
                        rows.sort(function(a, b) { return b[d] < a[d]; });
                        sortAscending = false;
                        this.className = 'aes';
                      } else {
                     rows.sort(function(a, b) { return b[d] > a[d]; });
                     sortAscending = true;
                     this.className = 'des';
                      }
                      
                     });
    
    var rows = tbl_ss564_ib.append('tbody').selectAll('tr')
                 .data(tbl_ss564_ib_jsonData).enter()
                 .append('tr');
    rows.selectAll('td')
      .data(function (d) {
       return title_ss564_ib.map(function (k) {
        return { 'value': d[k], 'name': k};
       });
      }).enter()
      .append('td')
      .attr('data-th', function (d) {
       return d.name;
      })
      .text(function (d) {
       return d.value;
      });
```

```css
* { 
   margin: 0; 
   padding: 0; 
     }
   #ss564_ib_page_wrap  body { 
    font: 14px/1.4 Georgia, Serif; 
     }
    #ss564_ib_page_wrap {
   margin: 20px;
    }
    p {
  margin: 20px 0; 
    }

 /* 
 Generic Styling, for Desktops/Laptops 
 */
 #ss564_ib_page_wrap table { 
  width: 100%; 
  border-collapse: collapse; 
 }
 /* Zebra striping */
 #ss564_ib_page_wrap tr:nth-of-type(odd) { 
  background: #eee; 
 }
 #ss564_ib_page_wrap th { 
  background: Teal;
  font-weight: bold; 
  cursor: s-resize;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: 3% center;
 }
 #ss564_ib_page_wrap td, th { 
  padding: 6px; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  text-align: left; 
 }
 
 #ss564_ib_page_wrap th.des:after {
      content: "\21E9";
    }
    
 #ss564_ib_page_wrap  th.aes:after {
      content: "\21E7";
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
 <div id="ss564_ib_page_wrap"> </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing your D3 code, the easiest solution is just manipulating your data array beforehand:

```
tbl_ss564_ib_jsonData[0].DC.forEach(function(d, i) {
    for (var key in d) {
        tbl_ss564_ib_jsonData[0][key] = d[key];
    }
});

delete tbl_ss564_ib_jsonData[0].DC;
```

Here is your code with that change:

```js
var tbl_ss564_ib_jsonData = [{
  "S_No": "1",
  "SS564 Metric": "Power Usage Effectiveness(PUE)",
  "Baseline": "2.2*",
  "DC": [{
      "A": "2.4"
    },
    {
      "B": "2.61"
    },
    {
      "C": "2.46"
    },
    {
      "D": "2.25"
    },
    {
      "E": "2.11"
    },
    {
      "F": "3.75"
    },
    {
      "G": "2.08"
    },
    {
      "H": "2.17"
    },
    {
      "I": "1.85"
    },
    {
      "J": "2.57"
    },
    {
      "K": "2.42"
    }
  ]
}];

tbl_ss564_ib_jsonData[0].DC.forEach(function(d, i) {
  for (var key in d) {
    tbl_ss564_ib_jsonData[0][key] = d[key];
  }
});

delete tbl_ss564_ib_jsonData[0].DC;

var sortAscending = true;
var tbl_ss564_ib = d3.select('#ss564_ib_page_wrap').append('table');
var title_ss564_ib = d3.keys(tbl_ss564_ib_jsonData[0]);
var header_ss564_ib = tbl_ss564_ib.append('thead').append('tr')
  .selectAll('th')
  .data(title_ss564_ib).enter()
  .append('th')
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .on('click', function(d) {
    header_ss564_ib.attr('class', 'header');

    if (sortAscending) {
      rows.sort(function(a, b) {
        return b[d] < a[d];
      });
      sortAscending = false;
      this.className = 'aes';
    } else {
      rows.sort(function(a, b) {
        return b[d] > a[d];
      });
      sortAscending = true;
      this.className = 'des';
    }

  });

var rows = tbl_ss564_ib.append('tbody').selectAll('tr')
  .data(tbl_ss564_ib_jsonData).enter()
  .append('tr');
rows.selectAll('td')
  .data(function(d) {
    return title_ss564_ib.map(function(k) {
      return {
        'value': d[k],
        'name': k
      };
    });
  }).enter()
  .append('td')
  .attr('data-th', function(d) {
    return d.name;
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.value;
  });
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#ss564_ib_page_wrap body {
  font: 14px/1.4 Georgia, Serif;
}

#ss564_ib_page_wrap {
  margin: 20px;
}

p {
  margin: 20px 0;
}


/* 
 Generic Styling, for Desktops/Laptops 
 */

#ss564_ib_page_wrap table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}


/* Zebra striping */

#ss564_ib_page_wrap tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: #eee;
}

#ss564_ib_page_wrap th {
  background: Teal;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: s-resize;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 3% center;
}

#ss564_ib_page_wrap td,
th {
  padding: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: left;
}

#ss564_ib_page_wrap th.des:after {
  content: "\21E9";
}

#ss564_ib_page_wrap th.aes:after {
  content: "\21E7";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="ss564_ib_page_wrap"> </div>
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your kind help. This is exactly what i need. Again, Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi sorry to bother, when i add second row, the row can't be seen.  Thank you so much for your help.  https://snag.gy/ybxBvw.jpg

Comment: @avamoe That's because my function deals with the data array as if it had only 1 object. If you have more objects, you have to change the function accordingly.